Chain slipping when under pressure
My chain slips when under pressure especially when I try to stand up or suddenly speed up. New chain a rear cogs and new cycle derailleur.
Cheers.

Does this answer your question? Chain slipping on middle chainring

Your chainring (or chainrings, plural) is/are probably worn out. Since that's the only load-bearing drivetrain component you didn't change, it would make sense that it is the culprit. Getting a video of your drivetrain in action would be a good way to confirm where the slippage is occurring, but my hunch is at the chainring(s).

So he should check and see if it happens on all chainrings if he has more than one.

@WornChain Whoops good point, some days I forget that the world of bicycles is not just single-chainring MTBs. Nice catch.
